# Mongod Replica set aborting after invariant() failure due to Stable timestamp Timestamp does not equal appliedThrough timestamp

Tags: mongodb

I am a newbie to MongoDB. I was doing a POC on consuming documents using Java Client. 
I am using a 4.2.5 version.
I have 3 instances of mongod running in my local with a Replica set as below.

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/d1/ --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost
mongod --port 27018 --dbpath /data/d2/ --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost
mongod --port 27019 --dbpath /data/d3/ --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost
```

After a certain time, one or two of the instance gets abended and when I tend to start again, I see the same error. I am not sure about what causes this error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Error:

```
2020-05-25T19:37:47.126+0530 I  REPL     [initandlisten] Rollback ID is 1
2020-05-25T19:37:47.128+0530 F  -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure !stableTimestamp || stableTimestamp->isNull() || appliedThrough.isNull() || *stableTimestamp == appliedThrough.getTimestamp() Stable timestamp Timestamp(1590410112, 1) does not equal appliedThrough timestamp { ts: Timestamp(1590410172, 1), t: 5 } src/mongo/db/repl/replication_recovery.cpp 412
2020-05-25T19:37:47.128+0530 F  -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after invariant() failure


2020-05-25T19:37:47.137+0530 F  -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Abort trap: 6).
 0x109e10cc6 0x109e1054d 0x7fff5d3c9b5d 0xa00 0x7fff5d2836a6 0x109e04d4a 0x1083597af 0x1083722ba 0x108376eb9 0x108077c6c 0x108071744 0x108070999 0x7fff5d1de3d5 0x9
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
"backtrace":[{"b":"10806F000","o":"1DA1CC6","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEE"},{"b":"10806F000","o":"1DA154D","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_110abruptQuitEi"},{"b":"7FFF5D3C5000","o":"4B5D","s":"_sigtramp"},{"b":"0","o":"A00"},
...
...
...
...
{ "path" : "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackgroundTaskManagement.framework/Versions/A/BackgroundTaskManagement", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF41F95000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF3C6CD000", "buildId" : "2A396FC07B7930889A82FB93C1181A57" }, { "path" : "/usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF5C842000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF56F7A000", "buildId" : "EC50E503AEEE3F50956F55E4AF4584D9" }, { "path" : "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/Versions/A/AppleSRP", "machType" : 6, "b" : "7FFF4177E000", "vmaddr" : "7FFF3BEB6000", "buildId" : "EDD16B2E4F353E13B389CF77B3CAD4EB" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEE+0x36) [0x109e10cc6]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_110abruptQuitEi+0xBD) [0x109e1054d]
 libsystem_platform.dylib(_sigtramp+0x1D) [0x7fff5d3c9b5d]
 ??? [0xa00]
 libsystem_c.dylib(abort+0x7F) [0x7fff5d2836a6]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo22invariantFailedWithMsgEPKcRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEES1_j+0x33A) [0x109e04d4a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl23ReplicationRecoveryImpl16recoverFromOplogEPNS_16OperationContextEN5boost8optionalINS_9TimestampEEE+0x43F) [0x1083597af]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl26ReplicationCoordinatorImpl21_startLoadLocalConfigEPNS_16OperationContextE+0x3AA) [0x1083722ba]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl26ReplicationCoordinatorImpl7startupEPNS_16OperationContextE+0xE9) [0x108376eb9]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_114_initAndListenEi+0x28FC) [0x108077c6c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111mongoDbMainEiPPcS2_+0xDA4) [0x108071744]
 mongod(main+0x9) [0x108070999]
 libdyld.dylib(start+0x1) [0x7fff5d1de3d5]
 ??? [0x9]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a [ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-37724) for this issue experienced by another user. You may consider engaging with MongoDB developers in that ticket to provide the requested information.